# Android SharedPreferences from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a `LoginFragment()` class and `ProfileFragment()` class which is implemented in `NavigationDrawerActivity`.

After logging in in `LoginFragment()`, `NavigationDrawerActivity` is started. 
When I press Settings in Navigation Drawer Activity there is `ProfileFragment`, where I can change a password of user or logout.

I have a problem with downloading user data in `ProfileFragment` from `LoginFragment`.

There is `SharedPreferences` editor, but it does not include my USER settings.

My code of logging process in LoginFragment():

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private AppCompatButton btn_login;
    private EditText et_email,et_password;
    private TextView tv_register;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view){

        pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);

        btn_login = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        tv_register = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_register);
        et_email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        progress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_register.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.tv_register:
                goToRegister();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_login:
                String email = et_email.getText().toString();
                String password = et_password.getText().toString();

                if(!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    loginProcess(email, password);

                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Uzupełnij pola!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

        }
    }
    private void loginProcess(String email,String password){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.LOGIN_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                    editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,true);
                    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,resp.getUser().getEmail());
                    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,resp.getUser().getName());
                    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,resp.getUser().getUnique_id());
                    editor.apply();
                    goToProfile();

                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void goToRegister(){

        Fragment register = new RegisterFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,register);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private void goToProfile(){
//        Fragment profile = new ProfileFragment();
//        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,profile);
//        ft.commit();
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Some of ProfileFragment() classes:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    pref = LoginFragment().pref;
    //pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = LoginFragment().editor;
    tv_name.setText("Welcome : "+pref.getString(Constants.NAME,""));
    tv_email.setText(pref.getString(Constants.EMAIL,""));

}
```

And:

```
private void logout() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false);
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,"");
    editor.apply();
    startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class));
}
```

How to solve it integrate one `SharedPreferences` with another? 
Thanks in advance!

Edit:// I start a ProfileFragment() class from MainActivity() (its navigation drawer) by :

```
            ProfileFragment galleryFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit,R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, galleryFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Comment: show complete LoginFragment class

Comment: and how are you doing something in logout method like
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); ?

Comment: Updated. But I don't understand the question. :(

Comment: show us complete LoginFragment class

Comment: I edited my thread. :) Check out.

Comment: pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()); in your LoginFragment

Comment: I have an error: http://prntscr.com/drv2w7

Comment: post your complete error as text and those seems like gradle errors , look for logcat errors

Comment: try rebuilding it

Comment: It works. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `getActivity().getPreferences(0);` use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` in your activity or `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());` in your fragment

Comment: I changed all getActivity().getPreferences(0); to PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()); in Fragments, but still does not work...

Comment: Instead of assigning that to a variable in your class, just retrieve it again whenever you need it. Remove `pref = LoginFragment().pref;` and make it match what I said above (`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`). You're initializing that variable in `initViews`, but you're trying to access it from a freshly created object, meaning `initViews` never runs, so that pref object is never initialized properly.

Comment: Works. Thanks! ;)